# How to design a table which have many-to-many relationship with itself?

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, orm

For example, A Users entity has a friends property, how can I design this friends property, in my thought there are 2 ways:

1. friends property is a String with all usernames splitted by "," in this way it's hard to read and modify.
2. friends property is a Set like `Set<Users>`, but in this way I don't know how to write in entities?

Anyone knows the best practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `User` can have multiple friends you could annotate your `User` entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_friends",
            joinColumns =
            { @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns =
            { @JoinColumn(
                    name = "friend_id") })
    private Set<User> friends;
}
```

This way a table will get created for `User` and a join table for the relationship between `User`s. The `User` table will have 2 columns, 'id' and 'name'. The `user_friend` table will have 2 columns, 'user_id' and 'friend_id'. The columns in `user_friend` are both foreign keys to the `User` table.

Comment: I tried and used the same JPA annotation as yours, it works. Thank you. Any other problem of this self-relation you think would cause later?

Comment: I assume that the friendship has to be visible to both users so you have to set the other end of the friendship. Other than a circular dependency I don't see any future problems. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is covered Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay.

A party represents a person (or an organization):

```
Party
id
name
```

A party can have a relationship to another party, over a time period:

```
PartyRelationship
fromPartyId
toPartyId
fromDate
toDate nullable
```

A basic diagram:

```
Party -< PartyRelationship >- Party
```

Sample SQL:

```
insert into party values (1, 'Jerry');
insert into party values (2, 'Neil');

insert into partyRelationship values (1, 2, getDate(), null);
```

Comment: Aww, their friendship will never end!